# Weird UI bleeding. Anyone know the cause/fix?

Tags: interface

I'm using Blender 2.71, and a day or two ago this weird UI glitch started occuring:

[image: screenshot of the bleeding]
^ Here's a screenshot of it.

The bleeding seems to trigger in various ways, the most common one being changing the user perspective viewing angle. The bleeding starts slow, going down one line at a time blurring the content (and diagonally, as you can see in the upper left).

Mousing over a bled UI element restores it to normal. I tried resetting to factory settings as well as changing the window size (full screen, small, etc) but to no avail.

I haven't had any graphical issues with other software (including games) so I doubt it's a graphics card issue.

I'm going to try and reinstall Blender and make sure my graphics drivers are up to date, hopefully that will work.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've sometimes had this problem with anti-aliasing (multisample) enabled. Does it help if you disable it in user-prefs > system?

Comment: It was already off. Only text aliasing was enabled, but after disabling it the problem still continued. Any other ideas..? EDIT: Changing Window Draw Method to "Overlap" seems to have stopped the issue. :D